# Last x Posted Categories?

Tags: categories, customization, widgets

Is there a widget available that will list the latest x categories according to posting date, essentially providing a list of the most recently active topics?

Comment: What if the latest post has two or more categories assigned to it and you wanted to show the latest 5 categories?

Comment: I guess I'd just have to add a check on $cat_array length in the snippet from krembo99 and stop when it gets to length 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
        $cat_array = array();
        $args=array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'posts_per_page' => 20,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1
          );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $cat_args=array('orderby' => 'none');
            $cats = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID , 'category', $cat_args);
            foreach($cats as $cat) {
              $cat_array[$cat->term_id] = $cat->term_id;
            }
          endwhile;
        }
        if ($cat_array) {
          foreach($cat_array as $cat) {
            $category = get_term_by('ID',$cat, 'category');
            echo '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($category, 'category')) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>'.'<br />';
          }
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Comment: just to confirm that code gets the categories of the last 20 posts and displays a link to the category page?